# Why golang custom error variable has multiple types

Tags: go, types, error-handling

i'm a new gopher and got really confused by variable types, if i'm defining a custom error

```
    import (
        "fmt"
        "reflect"
    )

    // custom errors
    type myError struct {
        msg string
    }

    func (m *myError) Error() string {
        return m.msg
    }

    func errorGen() error {
        return &myError{"custom error"}
    }
```

generate a new error and check the type of it

```
    func main() {
        e := errorGen()
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(e).Kind()) // type = pointer

        // first type assertion
        _, ok := e.(error)
        if ok {
            fmt.Println("type assertion error") // type = error
        }

        // second type assertion
        _, ok = e.(*myError)
        if ok {
            fmt.Println("type assertion *myError") // type = pointer
        }
    }
```

so in above code variable 'e' shows 2 types at the same time.
What exactly is e's type? and why "error" is an interface and also can be used as return type?

thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to differentiate between the "static type" and the "dynamic type" of a variable.

Each and every variable in Go has exactly *one* static type. Some example:

- After declaring `a := 5` the static type of `a` is `int` and that is all to know about `a`.
- The static type of `e` in your code is `error`(because that is what `errorGen` returns).
- You can be explicit about the static type like this: `var b uint16 = 9`.

Now there are interface types in Go. `error` is such an interface type, see Peter's answer. Some variables will have `error` as their static type; your `e` is an example. Now, the whole purpose of a variable of interface type is to store values of *various* types which implement this interface. So a interface variable which is not nil somehow "contains" an other variable (actually a value). The type of this contained value can be any one which implements the interface. The type of the contained value is the "dynamic type".
Type assertion let you extract values of this dynamic type.

Comment: why e's statistic type is `error` not a `pointer` considering `errorGen` is returning an address

Comment: Take a look at errorGen `func errorGen() error` it returns an `error`. The type returned is the type in the function signature. The function body stores a *myError inside a error and that error is returned. The return type of a function is determined _only_ by the function signature. Whatever you write after `return` is of no importance for the static return type (as long as it compiles).

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Errors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Errors)
>
> The predeclared type error is defined as
>
> ```
> type error interface {
>     Error() string
> }
> ```
>
> It is the conventional interface for representing an error condition,
>   with the nil value representing no error.
>
> [Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)
>
> An interface type specifies a method set called its interface. A
>   variable of interface type can store a value of any type with a method
>   set that is any superset of the interface. Such a type is said to
>   implement the interface.

---

`e` implements the predeclared interface type `error`.

```
    // first type assertion
    _, ok := e.(error)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("type assertion error") // type = error
    }
```

`e`'s concrete type is a pointer to type `myError`.

```
    // second type assertion
    _, ok = e.(*myError)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("type assertion *myError") // type = pointer
    }
```

Both type assertions are true (`ok` is `true`).